# JAVA: ANDROID: Word index of string

Tags: java, android, string, indexof

```
public void searchSong(String songToSearch){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), songToSearch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++ ){
        String value = fileArray[i].toLowerCase().replace(".mp3","");
        if (songToSearch.toLowerCase().matches(value) && !found) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            found = true;
        } else {
            found = false;
        }
        if(found){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the code to check if the songToSearch is a part of any string inside the fileArray 
Example lets say that fileArray[2] is equal to "Hello world" and the songToSearch is equal to "world" I would like to make the boolean found true... However this is not happening... the boolean never changes

Comment: you basically want search functionality for your songs list ? If yes you should try implementing search view.

Comment: use `value.toLowerCase().contains(songToSearch.toLowerCase())` instead of `matches`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Nah... It did not change the results

Comment: the boolean changes, but it also changes back on the next value which doesn't contain the word. do you want to show multiple results or just the first?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Wait... does not the && in the if stop the loop?

Comment: @DrunkProgrammer it does not : it stops checking the conditions if the first element is false. It's not a break statement. e.g. `if ((s != null) && (s.contains("bar"))){}` will not try to check if bar is contained in "s" if s is null

Answer (score 0):

see docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
public boolean  matches(String regex)
```

Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

you need:

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(songToSearch), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(value).find()) {
            playMusic(songToSearch);
        }
```

Would solve the problem... My post was actually a duplicate